# Solve equation which involves sum, binomial coefficient and erf

Tags: equation-solving, special-functions

I want to solve the following equation. Unfortunately solve doesn't do the job. Is there any other way or am I doing something wrong?

```
Solve[Sum[Binomial[8, d]*1/2*(1 + Erf[(-d + 0.5*(l + k))/(0.215*(l - k)*Sqrt[2])])
, {d, 0, 8}] == n, {k, l, n}]
```

$k, l, n$ are real numbers.

$n$ should be positive and

$k$ should be smaller than $l$.

I am relatively new to Mathematica and I am sorry if this problem is to trivial for you.

Comment: How would you expect to solve a function with errorfunctions in it analytically?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: I don't need an analytically correct answer. An approximation would be sufficient. But also NSolve and Reduce won't work

Comment: Well, There's only one equation and 3 unknown, so `NSolve[]` doesn't have enough to work on.

Comment: But it also doesn't work if I specify two variables...

Comment: `With[{k = 1, l = 2}, NSolve[]` Works fine for me. In fact, I can create an `InterpolationFunction`.

Comment: Of course it will work then. Then Solve is not needed. n should be a fixed variable.

Comment: Then the best you can do is an `InterpolationFunction[]`

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
FindInstance[Sum[Binomial[8, d]*1/2*(1 + Erf[(-d + 0.5*(l + k))/(0.215*(l - k)*Sqrt[2])]),{d, 0, 8}] == n && k < l && n > 0, {k, l, n}, Reals]
```

> {{k -> -0.24711, l -> 1, n -> 1}}?